# how to design OSM Cartridge using Design Studio without installing Weblogic and OSM?

Tags: weblogic, oracle-osm

I'm trying to design a cartridge on design studio, 
and everything goes well and deployed and tested,
but when adding any automation plugin in my project i'm getting an error that I must specify my Weblogic directory and OSM SDK Directory.

but these directories are on a server not on my machine how could i build such cartridge without installing OSM and weblogic on my machine???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting up an OSM cartridge workspace, you need to specify the OSM,WLS & JDK paths.

This is because some of its classes are needed by studio while compiling your cartridge.

Since, your local computer does not have these you could try  the below..

1) Note down the missing classes  which are pointed out by studio while trying to compile.

2) Identify the wls/osm jars which contain those classes

3) Create a local directory in you computer with these jars's and specify these jars in your project preferences.